# Below is an example of a square grid of dots with 3 dots along each side. In a similar square grid of dots with 8 dots along each

Tags: combinatorics

> Below is an example of a square grid of dots with 3 dots along each side. In a similar square grid of dots with 8 dots along each side, how many distinct lines pass through the dot at the bottom left corner and at least one other dot of the grid?

---

I am thinking this has to do something with slopes, since the slopes must be between 0 and 1 inclusive, where the denominator <= 7, but I can't figure out how to account for the overcounting, such as 1/2 and 2/4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the dot at the lower left corner at the origin of your coordinate frame and assume the spacing between adjacent dots is $1$.  Then except for the vertical line each line has the equation $y=mx$, where $m$ is a fraction with numerator and denominator between $0$ and $7$.

So how many distinct fractions of that form are there?  Pick up duplicates by reducing to lowest terms.

Denominator $7$:  There are $6$.
Denominator $6$:  There are $3$.
Denominator $5$:  There are $6$.
Denominator $4$:  There are $4$.
Denominator $3$:  There are $5$.
Denominator $2$:  There are $4$.
Denominator $1$:  There are $8$.

Add the vertical line, for a total of $37$ such lines.